Update a single point of a series in an echarts4r proxy in R Shiny
The code below observes a numeric input and multiplies the value corresponding to the "A" category by this number. Then, the proxy clears the chart (otherwise, it would draw another series) and draws a new series. Instead, is it possible to

Clear only the "A" category.
Redraw only the "A" category (so that the render animation leaves the other categories unchanged)
?

library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

# Sample data
fixed_data <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  value = c(10, 20, 30, 40)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("multiplier", "Choose a multiplier:", value = 1, min = 1, max = 10), br(),
  mainPanel(echarts4rOutput("barPlot"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Render the initial plot
  output$barPlot <- renderEcharts4r({
    fixed_data |> 
      e_charts(category) |> 
      e_bar(value) 
  })
  
  # Observe changes in numericInput and update the plot via proxy
  observeEvent(input$multiplier, {
    multiplier   <- input$multiplier
    updated_data <- fixed_data |> 
      mutate(value = ifelse(category == "A", value * multiplier, value))

    echarts4rProxy("barPlot", data = updated_data, x = category) |> 
      e_remove_serie("value") |> 
      e_bar(value) |> 
      e_execute()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

